# Is there a way to configure the output of git commit?

Tags: git, git-commit

I checked the man page for git-commit and search the webs but couldnt' find any reference to configuring the output of git commit.

By default, the output of of git commit looks like this:

```
[master 5d50e46]  #Bug#123 commit message"
53 files changed, 267 insertions(+), 173 deletions(-)
```

Is there an (easy or otherwise) way to override this output and make it either terser or more detailed?

Comment: What is your reason for trying to do so?

Answer (score 2):

> make it either terser or more detailed?

On the terser side, you have [`git commit --quiet`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit) (Suppress commit summary message.)

On the more detailed side, you would have to write your own wrapper for git commit in order to generate the output you want.
(as commented below, the `-v` option is about the editor message, not the output itself)

Comment: There is also the `-v` flag for more verbose output

Comment: @Trengot True, I was adding it to the answer when I saw your comment.

Comment: Just tried this and found no difference with or without `v` (with version 2.2.2).  Not sure why.

Comment: -v does *not* change the output of git commit. It changes what is being printed within the editor window (vim in my case) when you edit the commit message.

Comment: Regarding the wrapper that you mention, can you provide at least some general pointers as to where to look to have an idea how to start implementing one? Thanks.

Comment: @augustin not on the top of my head: the wrapper I see are more for prepraring the commit (like https://gist.github.com/sbrauer/6454801) than for reading its output

Comment: [delete:  double post]